# Group elements read from a txt file

Tags: python, list, grouping

I´m trying to figured out how to start with my code. I'm planning to do it with python.
I need to group elements that are going to be read from a txt file.
The txt file contains a list of Companies and Sites.
The sites depends from any specific Company on different locations.
The hard part is that the order of data in the txt file does not help to much.

See an example of the file.

```
Folder: Root\
Folder: Root\00 Company A\
Folder: Root\00 Company A\Local Sites
Site A Online
Site B Offline
Site C Online
Folder: Root\00 Company A\Remote Sites
Site D Online
Site E Offline

Folder: Root\01 Company B\
Folder: Root\01 Company B\Local Sites
Site N Offline
Folder: Root\01 Company B\Remote Sites
Site M Online
Site P Offline
```

This is a report that Networking team generate via an old software they use to monitoring sites.
The idea is to group Sites with Offline status by Company.
I'm having troubles trying to group Sites offline for each Company, since the only identifier for each Site is just the line that says "Root\XX Company X\Local Site" or "Remote Site"

Any idea on how to start?
Thanks

Comment: 1) Create a `dict` mapping company to list of offline sites; 2) iterate lines in file, remember last company name from "folder" line; 3) put all offline-sites you encounter into that last company's list in the dict.

Comment: If you have additional information to add to a question, you can (and should) just edit the question, don't add it in the comments. As for the question: try to break down the problem in steps. What part are you having trouble with? Opening and reading a text file? Identifying what type of line you're dealing with? Breaking up a text string in parts? Storing the information? Share what code you came up with so far and explain what problem you specifically have trouble with.